# Selecting A Dynamically Populated Radio Button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a survey with a bunch of questions which consist of the actual questions, some yes or no radio buttons and a comment box. I’ve included a picture to give you a visual. Here is the html structure after the questions have been populated.

```
<div class=”yesno-question-row”>

<span class=”yesno-question”> 

    Some Question………..

</span>

 <span class=”yesno-answer”>

     <span class=”yesno-radio required”>

           <input type=”radio” class=”yesno-radio-button” value=”Yes” />

           <input type=”radio” class=”yesno-radio-button” value=”No” />

     </span>

 <span class=”yesno-comment”>

           <textarea class="yesno-textarea ui-widget-content"></textarea>

 </span>

   </span>

</div>
```

This information is populated dynamically via a web service and jquery. Seeing as though these questions are being populated dynamically each question contains the same class name, span name, etc… There are over 40 questions, which are being appended to the div.

What I am trying to do is to select a specific question and have a specific radio button checked. Then if a certain radio button is clicked others are auto checked. I believe Jquery is my best bet, which led me to try to select the element by class—they all have the same class so that didn’t work, I tried to select the element by the hidden data attribute—that didn’t work seeing as though the attribute changes depending on who the survey is sent to. I tried doing more research and I think the next best thing is to use the jquery eq() attribute as I will be able to select an element based on it’s position. However I am having issues implementing this solution. If you have a better option or a visual example of how to best proceed I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the code, which create the questions;

```
  var $yesNoQuestionRow = $("<div class='yesno-question-row' data-answerid='" + answerId + "'/>");
            var question = "<span class='yesno-question'>" + questionText + "</span>";
            var radioId = "yesno" + answerId;
            var radioChecked = new Object();
            radioChecked[answerText] = "checked";
            var yesno = "<span class='yesno-radio required'><input class='yesno-radio-button' type='radio' name='" + radioId + "' value='Yes' " + radioChecked["Yes"] + ">Yes <input class='yesno-radio-button' type='radio' name='" + radioId + "' value='No' " + radioChecked["No"] + ">No</span>";
            var textarea = "<span class='yesno-comment'> <textarea class='yesno-textarea ui-widget-content'>" + commentText + "</textarea></span>";
            return $yesNoQuestionRow.append($(question)).append($("<span class='yesno-answer'/>").append($(yesno)).append($(textarea)));
```

Comment: Are you able to change the code that generated this html?

Comment: You can do it that way, but the code that you have to create them already allows you to give them unique identifiers. I wrote an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a dynamically named attribute that you (should) provide a unique name to for your elements, so you can use that to select them.

If, for instance, you create a `$yesNoQuestionRow` with `answerId = 2`, you can select the row and get the radio input value with this:

```
$(".yesno-question-row[data-answerid='2']").find(".yesno-radio-button:checked").val()
```

Edit: I just noticed that you said that you have a hidden data attribute that changes depending on the recipient. If that attribute is the `data-answerid` attribute, just create another  attribute that varies based on the question / answer and not on the recipient. Or you could just dynamically create unique, conventional `id` attributes.

Comment: Actually I just realized something, I would need to make sure the radio button is checked every time a survey went out. If the id is dynamic and we write a script that selects the element by it's id by the time the second survey goes it would break that code

Comment: I don't think I understand your application. What do you mean when you say  "every time the survey went out"? You've posted the apparent body of a function that you use to create a group of input elements and a truncated version of the resulting html. How is it that different clients will be receiving different versions of the page?

Comment: I guess my question is how would I target an element if its name is dynamic and there is now way to grab it by class? The data-answerid changes everytime an instance of the question is created.

Comment: Then create another attribute that doesn't change every time an instance of the question is created. Again, I don't understand your application and some background would be immensely helpful. I'll get you started. You have a web page that will be accessed by multiple clients. As each client interacts with the page, survey questions are added to the page. What causes these questions to be added? Where do the values for `answerId`, `questionText`, `answerText` and `commentText` come from?

Comment: When a user navigates to the survey page All survey question are added from the database via a loop, which appends each questions div to the parent div. The answerId is being supplied from the database’s store procedure and it ties a user’s answer with that instance of the survey. The questionText is also being supplied by the database as well as the answerText and commentText when user fills out the survey there information is stored/retrieved in the database under these three variables. Is there a way to use jquery contain or find features to select the specific div that houses some text